# FormData add file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, multipartform-data, form-data

I have form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post"  id="sendInvoiceForm">
    <input type="text" value="Some text">
    <input name="file[]" type="file"  multiple/>
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

My js:

```
$('#upload').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('files',$("#sendInvoiceForm")[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                type: 'POST',
                xhr: function() {
                    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    return myXhr;
                },
                success: function (data) {
                },
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
            return false;
        });
```

When I try to get my 'files' in php I get only **[object HTMLFormElement]**
How can I get my files on php?

But if I create my formData as :`var formData = new FormData($("#sendInvoiceForm")[0]);` 
I can find my files in _FILES, but I need give name for this array.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Name is already there  which is`file` you can access in php using `$_FILES['file']`. then what is the problem?

Comment: $_FILES is empty. I try `print_r($_FILES['files']);` and get error Undefined index: files

Comment: keep `var formData = new FormData($("#sendInvoiceForm")[0]);` and try `print_r($_FILES['file']);` in php

Comment: it helped me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're appending the `form` DOM Element to the FormData, not the file data. Instead, you should access the `files` array of that object:

```
formData.append('files', $('#sendInvoiceForm input[type="file"]')[0].files[0]);
```

As there can be multiple files selected, you'll need to loop through them:

```
$('#sendInvoiceForm input[type="file"]')[0].files.forEach(function(file) {
  formData.append('files', file, file.name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get error `TypeError: $(...)[0].files is undefined`

Comment: Apologies - my mistake with the wrong selector. I updated the answer for you